# "Hyacinths on (what I fondly call) my rockery"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

> Satin white, Persian purple, oil-paint yellow. When I planted these birches they were broomstick-height, and now look at them. They tap our bedroom window on stormy nights. **Hyacinths on (what I fondly call) my rockery**. Boy-blue and girl-pink. Through the kitchen double-doors I watch you eating supper – carrot and coriander soup – and leafing through Country Living Magazine, dreaming of houses uncluttered by reality, by half a lifetime of memories, perhaps.

Everyone calls Hyacinths as Hyacinths, because this is the original name of the flower called Hyacinths, so why the author say: "what I fondly call"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*What I fondly call* here is talking about *my rockery*, not about *hyacinths*.  Try to read the phrase without parentheses:

> Hyacinths on [ what I fondly call my rockery ]

A previously unnamed object (referred to by *what*) is being called *my rockery*.  Hyacinths are located on top of this object.

By the way, you don't need to capitalize *hyacinth* in English.  (Unless, as with any word, it's at the beginning of a sentence or being used as part of a proper noun, as in *Hyacinth Avenue* or Susan Vreeland's book *Girl in Hyacinth Blue*).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of acting as an appositive that refers to hyacinths, the parenthesized phrase modifies “my rockery”.  The implication seems to be that the garden where hyacinths and so forth grow was intended to be a [rockery](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rockery),  “a section of a garden made from decorative rocks and alpine plants”.  It may be that there are too few rocks, or not-decorative-enough rocks, to make it a rockery; or there may be other non-alpine plants besides the Mediterranean-origin hyacinths.

Answer (score 1):

He's being ironic. What is presumably just a pile of stones is something he fondly calls a rockery. The hyacinths are on the rockery.